# Show 404 when someone visits a non-existant Multisite site

Tags: multisite, redirect, 404-error

If we try to access a non-existant Multisite site, e.g., http://site1.example.com or http://example.com/site1/, we are redirected to http://example.com/wp-signup.php?new=site1.

How to block this and instead of it show 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

The option is in Network Admin, Settings, Network Settings, Allow new registrations

[image: Network Settings Registration Settings]

(screenshot from [WordPress's Managing a Multisite Network video](https://learn.wordpress.org/tutorial/managing-a-wordpress-multisite-network/))

You want either "Registration is disabled" or "User accounts may be registered".

Comment: Doesn't matter if its disabled, either way its redirects to wp-signup.php page, but just with message that registering is disabled.

Comment: Huh, fair enough. Last time I used a multisite it had fixed domain names not wildcard so there was no way to trigger this.

Comment: There must be a way to override that. I don't have time now but I'll have a look later.